# after running gradle script reports and test-result folder is not showing up

Tags: build.gradle

After running the gradle script the build is succesfull but no Reports, Test-Result folder is showing up under Build folder.

```
Project strutcture is :
Gateway
        src
            com.pojo - Person.java
            com.test -PersonTest.java
```

**Gradle script:**

```
apply plugin: 'java' 
apply plugin: 'war' 
apply plugin: 'eclipse'


    tomcat_home='C:/apache-tomcat-6.0.37-windows-x64/apache-tomcat-6.0.37'
    ext.projectJar = "C:/Users/r.kumar.verma/Desktop/referenceAppJar"

    version = "1.0-${new Date().format('yyyyMMdd')}"    
    sourceCompatibility = 1.7

    repositories {
                  mavenCentral()
                 }

    dependencies {
                  providedCompile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
                  runtime 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.1.2'
                  testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
                  compile fileTree(dir: projectJar, include: '*.jar')
                 }


**//This will publish the war to tomcat webapp.**
    task deploylocal(dependsOn: build) << {
        println "Copy from ${libsDir.getPath()} into ${tomcat_home}/webapps"
        copy{
              from libsDir
              into "${tomcat_home}/webapps"
              include '*.war'
            }
      }
```

**After running gradle test below is the output:**

```
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test UP-TO-DATE

**After running gradle build, below is the output:**

:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:war
:assemble
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test UP-TO-DATE
:check UP-TO-DATE
:build

I am not clear why the folders are not getting created under it.
I did clean build and all other things.
```

Person class is just a POJO with String name and the test is just checking the assert where the input and output is equal or not..

```
Gateway
            src
                com.pojo - Person.java
                com.test -PersonTest.java
```

**Person.java:**

```
public class Person {
    private final String name;

        public Person(String name) {
            this.name = name;
          }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

**PersonTest.java**

```
import org.junit.Test;

import com.marriott.dsap.gateway.pojo.Person;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class PersonTest {
    @Test
    public void canConstructAPersonWithAName() {
        Person person = new Person("Larry");
        assertEquals("Larry", person.getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution I've found is to organise the project layout as described on the Gradle website **chapter 23.4** http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html

You should try to create and put the file ***PersonTest.java*** in the folder **/ProjectXXX/src/test/java/*PersonTest.java***

It worked for me.